# Skipping data in winsock?

Tags: winapi, asynchronous, tcp, winsock, skip

Is it possible to skip a portion of the incoming data on a TCP stream socket, instead of having to read it into a buffer? Preferably, I'm looking for something that also works asynchronously.

Comment: Why not just write the data into a buffer and then overwrite them again when valid data come in?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just read it and discard it.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. 
Read it into another buffer.